Largest collection in Sperner's theorem is either $\binom{[n]}{\lfloor {n/2} \rfloor}$ or $\binom{[n]}{\lceil {n/2} \rceil}$
The set families $\binom{[n]}{\lfloor {n/2} \rfloor}$ and $\binom{[n]}{\lceil {n/2} \rceil}$ are the only independent systems in $2^{[n]}$ with the largest possible number of sets.
I know that if I choose $k$ elements in $[n]$, $\binom{[n]}{\lfloor {n/2} \rfloor}$ and $\binom{[n]}{\lceil {n/2} \rceil}$ are the largest. But how can I prove that the other ways to choose elements are not able to reach the largest number of sets?(By Sperner, we know that any independent system $F$ in $2^{[n]}$, $F$ satisfies $|F| \le \binom{n}{\lfloor {n/2} \rfloor}$)

Well, you can take proof of Sperner theorem and derive the structure from there. Here is the proof for the case of even $n = 2m$, for odd $n$ the same idea works with some additional details. Let $S_k$ be the set of all subsets of size $k$.
Lemma. If $k <  m$ the there exists an injective mapping $f_k\colon S_k\to S_{k + 1}$ such that $f_k(S)\subset S$ for every $S\in S_k$. Similarly, for $k < m$ there is such injection $S_{k}\to S_{k - 1}$.
Proof of lemma. We construct a bipartite graph between  $S_k$ and $S_{k + 1}$, were $A\in S_k$ and $B\in S_{k + 1}$ are connected if and only if $A\subset B$. Degree of the vertices from $S_k$ is $n - k$ and the degree of the vertices from $S_{k + 1}$ is $k  < n - k$. Hence the lemma follows from the Hall's marriage theorem.
Assume that there is an independent system $M$ of size ${n}\choose{m}$ which is not $S_m$. Let $k_1 <  \ldots < k_l$ be numbers such that $M\cap S_{k_i}\neq\emptyset$. If $k_1 < m$ then we can change every element $X$ in $M\cap S_{k_i}$ to $f_{k_i}(X)$ without breaking the independence assertion. If we perform this operation several times we can get the situation where we have only two numbers $k_1 < k_2$, where $(k_1, k_2) = (m, m + 1)$ or $(k_1, k_2) = (m - 1, m)$. Let us stick with the second case. Recall the graph from the lemma. We know that $M\cap S_{m - 1}$ connected only with $S_m\setminus (M\cap S_{m})$. Also $|M| = |S_m|$ hence $|M\cap S_{m - 1}| = |S_m\setminus (M\cap S_{m})|$, however this contradicts the structure of the graph.

You say that your proof also works when $n$ is odd "with some additional details", but I think the Devil is in those details. Could you edit your answer to explain the proof of the odd case? With $n=7$, for example, why can't you have an antichain with $20$ sets of size $3$ and $15$ sets of size $4$?

@MikeEarnest, you are right. When $n = 2m + 1$ is odd, there is a case when $M\cap S_m$ is connected only with $S_{m + 1}\setminus (M\cap S_{m + 1})$. However, this is not possible because the graph is connected. No Devil there :)

First, I prove that any antichain in $2^{[n]}$ with cardinality $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ must only consist of subsets with size $\lfloor n/2\rfloor $ and $\lceil n/2\rceil.$ In the case where $n$ is even, this fully answers your question. When $n$ is odd, we need a little more work, which I do at the end.
My proof uses the LYM inequality. This inequality states that for an antichain in $2^{[n]}$ which has $a_k$ subsets of size $k$ for each $k\in \{0,1,\dots,n\}$, then
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\binom nk}\le 1
$$
First of all, the LYM inequality implies that any antichain has size at most $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$, as shown below.
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n a_k
\stackrel{*}\le \sum_{k=0}^n a_k\cdot \color{blue}{\frac{\binom n{\lfloor n/2\rfloor }}{\binom nk}}
=\binom n{\lfloor n/2\rfloor }\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\binom nk}
\stackrel{\text{LYM}}\le \binom n{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\cdot 1.
$$
Now, consider the marked inequality. If there exists $k$ such that $a_k\neq 0$, and such that $k\not\in \{\lfloor n/2\rfloor, \lceil n/2\rceil\}$, then the $\stackrel{*}\le$ inequality  will be a strict inequality. This is because the factor $\color{blue}{{\binom n{\lfloor n/2\rfloor }}/{\binom nk}}$ being multiplied by $a_k$ on the RHS is strictly greater than $1$. Since the entire inequality is strict, the size of the antichain is strictly less than $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$. This shows that a maximal antichain can only have $a_k\neq 0$ for $k\in \{\lfloor n/2\rfloor, \lceil n/2\rceil\}$, which was what I claimed to prove.
Since we are done when $n$ is even, let $n$ be odd. Consider the bipartite graph, on vertex set $A\cup B$, where $A$ is the set of subsets with size $(n-1)/2$,  $B$ is the set of subsets with size $(n+1)/2$ and subset $S\in A$ is joined to $T\in B$ when $A\subseteq B$. We must show that the only maximal independent subsets in this graph the parts $A$ and $B$.
For any collection of subsets $E\subseteq A$, let $N(E)$ be the set of neighbors of $E$, so that $T\in N(E)$ if and only if there exists $S\in E$ with $S$ joined to $T$. I claim that, for all $E\subseteq A$, except for the trivial cases where $E=\varnothing$ and $E=A$, then $|N(E)|>|E|$. This claim solves the problem; if $\mathcal C$ is any antichain where $\mathcal C\neq A$ and $\mathcal C\neq B$, then
$$
|\mathcal C|=|\mathcal C\cap A|+|\mathcal C\cap B|\le |C\cap A|+|B|-|N(\mathcal C\cap A)|<|B|=\binom{n}{(n+1)/2}.
$$
Note that this bipartite graph is regular, with degree $(n+1)/2$. This means the graph has a perfect matching. This quickly implies $|N(E)|\ge |E|$, as $N(E)$ contains all of the sets matched with $E$ in this matching. Assume by way of contradiction that $|N(E)|=|E|$. I claim that this implies $E\cup N(E)$ is a connected component. Letting $k=(n+1)/2$ be the degree of the graph, then there are $k\cdot |E|$ edges coming out of $E$, all of which go into $N(E)$. Similarly, there are $k\cdot |N(E)|=k\cdot |E|$ edges coming out of $N(E)$; these edge must all go into $E$, to account for all $k\cdot |E|$ edges coming out of $E$. This proves $E\cup N(E)$ is a connected component. But the bipartite graph on $A\cup B$ is connected (prove this), so this means that $E=\varnothing$ or $E=A$, as claimed.
